# Date difference using sas macro

Tags: sas

```
I have two macro variables value.

 a=20150501
 b=20160530
```

I want to create a new macro variable that will display the number of months between a and b.

Comment: What did you try?  What did you do to convert the strings that you have in your macro variables to actual SAS date values?

Comment: How are you defining 'month'? If a date is February 29th and the next date is March 1st what's the expected answer? A month is not a consistent measure of time, like week or day.

Answer (score 2):

Same logic as Allan's response but using a data step to simplify the code...

```
%let a = 20150501;
%let b = 20160530;

data _null_;
  a = input(put("&a", 8.), yymmdd8.);
  b = input(put("&b", 8.), yymmdd8.);
  diff = intck("month", a, b);
  call symputx("diff", put(diff, best.));
run;

%put &diff;

12
```

See documentation for `intck` for alternative ways to calculate the difference in months.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INTCK function for that - see [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212868.htm)

```
%let a=20150501;
%let b=20160530;

/**
 * first - convert to date values
 * (DATE_A=01MAY2015 DATE_B=30MAY2016)
 */
%let date_a=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(
        INPUTN(%sysfunc(PUTN(&a, Z8.)), YYMMDD8.)
    ), date9.));
%let date_b=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(
        INPUTN(%sysfunc(PUTN(&b, Z8.)), YYMMDD8.)
    ), date9.)); 
%put &=date_a &=date_b;

/**
 * Now calculate difference using INTCK
 * (DIFF=12)
 */
%let diff=%sysfunc(intck(MONTH,"&date_a"d,"&date_b"d));
%put &=diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `intck()` function to get the number of months difference.

If you are performing a calculation such as age, or tenure, then be sure to use the 'continuous' parameter of `intck()`.

If you simply need to know that there is 1 month difference between the 31-May and the 01-Jun, then use the 'discrete' (default) parameter.

```
%let a=20150531;
%let b=20150601;

* CONVERT TO SAS DATES;
%let date1 = %sysfunc(inputn(&a,yymmdd8.));
%let date2 = %sysfunc(inputn(&b,yymmdd8.));

* CALCULATE # DISCRETE MONTHS DIFFERENCE;
%let discrete_months = %sysfunc(intck(month, &date1, &date2, d));
%put &=discrete_months;

* CALCULATE # CONTINUOUS MONTHS DIFFERENCE;;
%let cont_months = %sysfunc(intck(month, &date1, &date2, c));
%put &=cont_months;
```

Output:

```
DISCRETE_MONTHS=1
CONT_MONTHS=0
```